# Selenium WebDriver throws WebDriverTimeoutException on RemoteWebElement.Click()

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an error with clicks that hard to reproduce. 1-2/10000 clicks ends with `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException`.
It looks like element was not clicked and driver waits for some reaction.

```
Message: timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.028
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
Stack trace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
```

Sometimes Timeout in exception message looks legit (300 seconds), but in most cases it has negative value like -0.028.

I use:

```
Chrome 52.0.2743.116
Selenium 2.53.1
ChromeDriver 2.23 (also produces with 2.22)
```

Update:

I start getting this error also on `RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl`

```
Type: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException
Message: timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.032
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
Stack trace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
```

Comment: It would be great if you paste the code.

Comment: @amitbobade it happens in pretty much places I call `IWebElement.Click()`, but very rare and unpredictable.

Comment: Cool. What's the ChromeDriver version?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I think I faced similar issue and then I downgraded the ChromeDriver version to 2.18. But latest ChromeDriver version 2.23 is available now. Try upgrading your current ChromeDriver version to 2.23. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: @amitbobade thanks. My current version 2.22, I'll upgrade to 2.23.

Comment: Cool. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @amitbobade upgrade doesn't help. I am still getting this error in rare occasions, that ruin reports a bit

Comment: Ohh. Did you try downgrading the ChromeDriver to 2.18?

Comment: Try to debug your test and make sure that it's not about your element being not visible at the moment you click it. Make sure the page is loaded and ajax requests are executed.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba elements are fine. In other way I should get WebDriverException, InvalidElementStateException or something like that. In browser it looks like it waits for something but nothing happens.

Comment: @KovpaevAlexey so you want to say your page is not in a loading process and elements are not loaded by any ajax. And the error occurs even in debug mode?

Comment: @DenisKoreyba this issue is rare and inconsistent to catch it in debug. It happens ~3-5 times per 1000-2000 test-cases*portal. I just find sometimes the page that stuck on something. For example tab in Chrome already has new URL but old page and it waits for 300 secs then raises that exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by reducing degree of parallelism of my test runner from 30 to 10. It looks like overusing CPU causes requests not to reach web drivers for some reason.

Comment: Hi - were did you change this setting?  I am facing a similar issue

Comment: Hi, @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat. I used my custom test runner for managing concurrent webdriver's execution, so I just reduced degree of parallelism to fix that and that worked for me. Probably `ChromeDriver` is not intended to be used in highly concurrent systems.

Comment: I am using Test Explorer in VS Ent 2017. Any tests that go over 5 mins times out. Tests runs fine in IE. This is a  unique issue in Chrome. My tests are in NUNIT Framework and written in C#.  See the code below.
    `driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(700));
 driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(700)`

Answer (score 1):

Little peak into the Selenium source code will reveal that every action on the `WebElement` or infact any Selenium interaction will invoke `execute(String driverCommand, Map<String, ?> parameters)` of [RemoteWebDriver class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#L634)

This will execute command through the `CommandExecutor` [Interface](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CommandExecutor.java) which is implemented by different drivers

ChromeDriver also implements this and you are seeing this error due to a bug which chromium team is aware and is working on. please check the bug details here.

The error rate has come down with Chromedriver v2.23 but its still occurring but rarely

[Bug#1362](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1362)

[Bug#817](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=817)

[Bug#1224](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1224)

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the issue, at least for my case. We were running the selenium tests on a Jenkins machine which was using a proxy server. We came across this issue only when we enabled logging to All. Its a known fact that websockets do not work with proxies and chromedriver uses websockets to fetch browser logs. So we disabled proxy and the issue is resolved.